# C# backwards compatibility

Tags: c#, .net, backwards-compatibility

1. I am using windows 7 running .net 4.0
2. I wrote an application on my platform then distributed it to my coworkers.
3. They are   using windows XP .net 3.0 and 3.5
4. They can not update to .net 4 for business reasons.
5. I am running Visual studio 2010

How can i make my application backwards compatible so that they can use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't use any .NET 4 specific features, just target 3.0 or 3.5. That will solve any compatibility problems. Here's a link on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772098%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) detailing how to do it:

> - On the Project menu, click ProjectName Properties.
> - Click the Application tab.
> - In the Target Framework list, select either .NET Framework 2.0, .NET
>     Framework 3.0, or .NET Framework 3.5.

Comment: @toosweetnitemare: added a link to the relevant documentation. That will help.

Comment: @alex I have built an app in 4.0 but I want the application to run in all version, I mean 3.5, 3.0.

Comment: @ImranKhanHunzai applications created in previous versions of .NET (e.g. 3.0) will work if you have .NET 4 installed on your PC. However, applications targeting .NET 4 will not run if you only have an older version of the framework on your machine.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use .NET 4.0 features and set the target framework to .NET 3.5 on your project.
Then rebuild and redistribute. How to do it:

> - In Visual Studio, open the project you
>     want to change.
> - Right-click the project in Solution
>     Explorer and then click Properties.
> - In the Project Designer, locate the
>     Target Framework list, as follows.
> - For Visual C# projects, the Target
>     Framework list is on the Application
>     tab of the Project Designer. For more
>     information, see Application Page,
>     Project Designer (C#).
> - In the Target Framework list, select
>     the .NET Framework version or profile
>     that you want.

More detailed information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx).

Also, about don't using 4.0 features, you can read more about what [C# features here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796223.aspx).

Comment: @toosweetnitemare: remeber to mark as the accepted answer if it really solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Target the .Net v3.51 framework in your project

Comment: You should explain *how* to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Only use features supported by .net 3.5.  Don't use any .net 4.0+ features.

Comment: @toos you can set your webserver to run in .net 3.5 and then run it, refactoring any pieces of code that throw errors because 3.5 doesn't support them.